# Is normalization factor applicable to AWS EC2 Windows Reserved instaces?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-reserved-instances

Normlization factor is explained on this page - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/apply_ri.html

Just adding example from above page for clarity,"t2.medium instance has a normalization factor of 2. If you purchase a t2.medium default tenancy Amazon **Linux/Unix** Reserved Instance in the US East (N. Virginia) and you have two running t2.small instances in your account in that Region, the billing benefit is applied in full to both instances"

Is the same kind of flaxibility availabe for windows EC2 instaces?

Thank You!!

Comment: Yes. You reserve purchase instance type/size/region/tenancy/class. What you install on it is up to you including whatever OS you want on it. More about it here at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-reserved-instances.html

Comment: Thanks @Asdfg, but is this documented anywhere with example of windows reserved instance? Good to have this documented as in all the examples on normalization factor AWS team has mentioned Linux instaces and windows instances are not mentioned. 

Also, I read somewhere  there windows reserved instances does not have same flaxibility as Linux reservred instances. (though not sure how correct is that). That is one more season why it's good to have something documented.

Answer (score 0):

Got one link where it says the this normalization does not apply to windows or RHEL
https://nutanix.medium.com/aws-ec2-reserved-instances-choosing-the-right-one-that-fits-you-cf3e567c96b8

I will also check this with AWS Support